# python - bit shift on positive integer producing negative integer ... how could this happen?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created a Python 3 BitSet class that I'm using for fast set operations on the domain of integers starting at 0.

I'm running into a bug in a graph-based algorithm using the BitSet. My debugging code

```
print(v)
print(v == 63)
print(1 << v)
```

produces the following output (note the sign on the final line):

```
63
True
-9223372036854775808
```

When I try the following in the interpreter, I get the positive answers I'm looking for:

```
>>> 1 << 63
9223372036854775808
>>> x = 1 << 61 | 1 << 63
>>> x
11529215046068469760
>>> bin(x)
'0b1010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

One clue is that the first place this code produces a bug is close to the sys.maxsize for my system (9223372036854775807, or 2^63 - 1).

Any thoughts on what could cause this behavior?

**What I've tried so far**

I've tried to read everything possible on integer overflow, etc. I wouldn't have thought that Python 3 (with it's arbitrary-length integers) would generate this kind of error.

Comment: Can't reproduce this here. Python 3.4.0/3.3.5 (both Win7 x64) gives `9223372036854775808` as output for `print(1 << v)`.

Comment: Have you double checked there's nothing wrong in the `BitSet` class? Can't reproduce.

Comment: @unutbu: Don't know my own code well enough ... it's actually numpy.int64. Hmmm ... that could be an issue.

Comment: Well, that's obviously it :)

Comment: Doh ... so embarrassed. Sorry all.

Answer (score 0):

If a binary represented integer has the most significant bit as "1", then it is considered a negative number.

Read more here:

[Two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)